# Listar un registro por página en ReportView .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, reportviewer

Tengo un conjunto de datos DataSet pero no deseo mostrarlos en una tabla,
sino un registro por página estoy utilizando textbox pero solo me aparece el primer registro luego aparecen tantas páginas vacias como registros existan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es que con textbox no va a funcionar, necesitas usar un Table, Tablix, etc para que actue como detalle

[HOw to fix No of Rows per page in SSRS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/16eee49a-53d2-49cf-a7fd-9f6f10a1eb5b/how-to-fix-no-of-rows-per-page-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices)

como veras la idea es definir una table en donde indicas el `Page Breaks` con una formula que indique como cortar los registros por pagina

[How to: Add a Page Break (Report Designer)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156434(v=SQL.90).aspx)